# printing an array with arbitrary nesting levels, in java

Tags: java

My problem is bit simple but I am not able to get my head around it (new in java).

I have a list and i want to print it.

Now the issue is some elements of the list can be list itself.

For example:

```
["foo",1,2,[22,23],[1,[22,[23]]] ... ]
```

I want to print this in depth fashion which means, that the output be:

```
"foo", 1,2,22,23, 1,22,23..
```

How do I do this in java

Comment: have you tried just to call .toString() on the list? it calls to string on all its elements aswell.

Comment: Are you sure this is Java? This looks Pythonesque(dynamically typed list).

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk This can be a `List<Object>` in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this recursivly by checking if the current element is again a list and by using the `toString`-method which every object in java has.

```
public void printList(List<Object> a)
{
    for (Iterator<Object> it = a.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Object item = it.next();
        if (item instanceof List) printList((List<Object>) item);
        else System.out.print(item + ", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it recursively. Pseudo-code:

```
function printRecursively (list):
    for item in list:
        if item is Array:
            printRecursively(item)
        else:
            printItem(item)
```

Comment: @maazza As I clearly said, it’s pseudo-code.